# What are the benefits of being able to remove somatic components from casting a spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spellcasting, spell-components

**What are the full benefits if somatic components are removed from casting a spell (ie. using [still spell](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Still%20Spell) metamagic feat.)?**

A lot of d20 based video games have the benefit of removing the arcane spell failure when somatic components are removed from spellcasting. I was wondering if this is the same in pathfinder 1e tabletop game, and if there are any other not-so-obvious benefits that would come from this.

Comment: “Look mom, no hands!”

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Ignoring arcane armor failure

> [Spells [...] might fail if you’re wearing armor while casting a spell **with somatic components**.](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#Spell_Failure)

(Emphasis mine.)

The first and foremost reason to remove somatic components from spellcasting, which videogames got right, is that arcane spell failure is caused by your armor limiting your movements and getting in the way of spellcasting.

Remove the need to move and you won't fail your spell due to your armor.

## Ignoring the inability to gesture

### ...if you're unable to move

> [To cast a spell, you must be able to [...] gesture (if it has a somatic component)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#Choosing_a_Spell)

If you're somehow not able to move, you can't gesture and the only spells you can cast are those without a somatic component.

*Hold person* or anything that imposes the Paralyzed condition make you unable to move, as does being [Grappled](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Cast-a-Spell) or worse [Pinned](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#Grappled_or_Pinned).

Keep in mind that some spells require you to do some specific movement (like fanning your hands in front of you or pointing a finger to the target) that might or might not be part of the somatic components, so maybe don't try to still those spells because they might not work anyway.

Spells that require you to look a certain way—such as all *detect something* spells—will work if stilled, but you won't be able to choose which direction you're looking at.

Keep in mind that being unable to move will also block your mouth, making it impossible to cast spells with Verbal components as well. (Thanks [Ben S](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/35341/ben-s) for reminding me.)

### ...if you're polymorphed into something that can't gesture

> [...] [While in such a form, you [...] and can only cast spells with somatic [...] components if the form you choose has the capability to make such movements](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#Transmutation)

## Casting when your hands are all occupied

> [You must have at least one hand free to provide a somatic component.](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#Components)

If your hands are full, you can only cast spells that don't have somatic (nor material) components. Some class features might give you ways to work around that, as is the case for the Magus.